# Postgres how to find records inserted in last one minute from database?

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to check that the records inserted in table should not be more than 5 in a minute.
For that,
While saving my record, I am inserting time using offsetdatetim, which is following format:

```
`"2022-05-03 20:11:46.872"`
```

(timestamp without timezone type in db)
Now, to check:

```
select * from everify where sentDate > current_timestamp - interval '1 minutes';
```

This query returns all records.

Please suggest query to fetch records within 1 minute.
I think there is problem with timestamp.

Comment: When sentDate is a timestamp without timezone and current_timestamp does have a timezone, you might have a problem. Did you try LOCALTIMESTAMP instead of current_timestamp ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Tried, same. all records are getting fetched.

Comment: Show us your data, show an example on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14

Comment: 1) Is the timestamp being inserted into `sentDate`? 2) What is `offsetdatetim`? 3) Have you checked `sentDate` to see if there are values older then `current_timestamp - interval '1 minutes'`? Or are they all current?